# Filter on algolia facets which are stringified jsons

Tags: json, facet, algolia, faceted-search

I have an algolia index.
One of the facets, Tags is like this

```
{"_id":"56179ac8c5c84cda2d036a88","type":"tag","slug":"budget","title":"budget"}
```

Was a JSON. I saved it as JSON.stringify(tag) to be able to make it as a facet.

Another facet is of city.

```
https://JKHJHKMN.algolia.net/1/indexes/data/?facetFilters=city:Delhi
```

This works.

But,

```
 https://JKHJHKMN.algolia.net/1/indexes/data/?facetFilters=Tags:{"_id":"56179ac8c5c84cda2ddhd7a88","type":"tag","slug":"budget","title":"budget"}
```

The above query does not.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation where I have a facet where each item has a user-visible label and an API-friendly slug. If I could have something like the slug returned in the meta data in the same way `count` is, that'd solve my problem. is the only way of doing something like this to stringify the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Tags object as facets you should:

1. Have `Tags` as an `attributes for faceting` => all the property of Tags will become one different facet.
2. Using the `filters` search parameters, you would have something like:

`Tags._id:56179ac8c5c84cda2d036a88 AND Tags.type:tag AND Tags.slug:budget AND Tags.title:budget`

=> Here's the [documentation of filters](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/). We advise using it over `facetFilters`as it provides an easier SQL-like syntax to use.

Comment: Actually, In my result set, i need the whole object together as i wanna use it. If i facet every field, i wont be able to do that

Comment: You should see your whole `tags` objects. It's not what you're experiencing? What library from Algolia are you using? Can you provide a live example?